# How to make this higher resolution transform as fast as Fourier?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, fourier-analysis

Given a table of data, the Fourier command gives the discrete frequency content of the data, where the resolution in frequency space is equal to 1/N, where N is the number of data points.

Higher resolution can be obtained with the same set of data by writing a custom Fourier command which samples frequencies in between those sampled by the Mathematica command. However, a naive application of this is very slow. For example, the following, for sets of real-valued data parametrized by k and m,

```
{kmax, mmax} = {2, 2};
Do[data[k][m] = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 200}], {k, 1, kmax}, {m, 1, mmax}];
lenn = Length@data[1][1];
frac = 1/2;
fou = Table[Exp[2*Pi*I*(r - 1)*(s - 1)/lenn], {r, 1, lenn}];
Do[myFourier[k][m]=Table[Abs[Total[data[k][m]*fou]], {s, 1, lenn, frac}], {k, 1, kmax}, {m, 1, mmax}]; //Timing
```

takes about 1.4s to run on my computer. This is ~1000 times slower than

```
Do[Fourier[data[k][m]], {k, 1, kmax}, {m, 1, mmax}]; // Timing
```

which takes 0.0013s.

My understanding is that the Mathematica Fourier command is already optimized, and so I have attempted to Compile this code in various ways, but have not been able to find a successful implementation.

The question is, why is this simple table multiplication so slow, and can Compile be used to increase its efficiency?

Comment: Just for curiosity, in which situation will this technique make the frequency resolution higher? I just tested with a `Sin[Range[50.]]` list, but only find some small spurious peak generated, the shape of main peak seems to remain unchanged.

Comment: @xzczd I was looking at `Table[Sin[2*Pi*f*t], {t, 0, 1, inc}]` where `inc` is very small (say ~0.005). The table looks nearly continuous and the frequency can be determined by eye. However, for `f=1.5`, for example, or any non-integer `f`, Fourier does not fully capture the peak.

Comment: So, this technique is useful when the original frequency resolution isn't that good?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It might be useful given a data set which is short (in the time domain, for example), but which has a high sampling rate. `Fourier` gives low resolution plots, even though more information is contained in the data, because `Fourier` only samples integer multiples of the fundamental frequency `1/T`, where `T` is the length of the data in time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substantial speed improvement can be made by using machine arithmetic throughout. For example, could do as below.

```
fourierVec[s_, n_] := Exp[2.*Pi*I*Range[0., n - 1]*(s - 1)/n]

n = 2*10^2;
data = RandomReal[1, n];
```

No interpolation in this experiment, just comparing time and values to `Fourier`.

```
Timing[
 four1 = 1/Sqrt[N[n]]*Table[data.fourierVec[s, n], {s, n}];]
Timing[four2 = Fourier[data];]
Max[Abs[four1 - four2]]

(* {0.015625, Null}

{0., Null}

8.04419*10^-14 *)
```

Now compute with the half-stride.

```
Timing[
 myFourier1 = 1/Sqrt[N[n]]*Table[data.fourierVec[s, n], {s, 1., n, .5}];]

(* Out[124]= {0.03125, Null} *)
```

Not so bad. But we are running an O(n^2) algorithm and that is simply not going to scale like `Fourier` at O(n log n). Can we recover this result using just `Fourier`? Yes, if we compute an "offset" FT and riffle with the regular FT.

```
Timing[
 myFourier2 = 
   Riffle[Fourier[data], Most@Fourier[fourierVec[1.5, n]*data]];]
Max[Abs[myFourier1 - myFourier2]]

(* Out[132]= {0., Null}

Out[133]= 8.3098*10^-14 *)
```

This can be extended in a fairly straightforward manner to other fractions.
It appears to be substantially the same as the interpolation variant given by @JohnDoty, other than the issue of dropping the last value (which I did in order to get agreement with the corrected DFT from the original post).

Comment: Because of the improved scaling with n, this reduces my runtime from 8hrs to 0.9s, so thanks! The key philosophy change from my approach and attempts with `Compile` is that you simply apply the usual `Fourier` but modify it by shifting the exponential. Very smooth.

Comment: A heterodyne Fourier transform. I used this method, with a big frequency shift and decimation, to compute fragments of long transforms on a minicomputer for my MIT Ph.D. thesis in 1978. I think the padding method is simpler for interpolation.

Comment: @JohnDoty (1) Some testing also indicates the zero padding method is a hair faster, if you use machine double zeros. (2) I have an unrelated question for you which I will raise off-forum. (3) I do recall creating beats from near-equal signal pairs, but the term "heterodyne" was new to me. (4) Not many of us still around who remember minicomputers (let alone worked with them).

Answer (score 5):

`Fourier` uses the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT), much faster than a direct method. But you can easily create what you want just by padding the data with zeros, since the delta frequency is inversely related to the array length.

```
dat = RandomReal[1, 10];
Fourier[dat]
(* {1.53116 + 0. I, -0.0783886 - 0.207404 I, -0.298173 + 
    0.179654 I, -0.0245808 + 0.0339534 I, -0.0390086 + 
    0.501077 I, -0.075875 + 0. I, -0.0390086 - 0.501077 I, -0.0245808 - 
    0.0339534 I, -0.298173 - 0.179654 I, -0.0783886 + 0.207404 I} *)
```

Interpolate with a padded FFT. `n` interpolation factor. The `Sqrt` is to get the normalization the same as the unpadded:

```
interpolatedFourier[dat_, n_] := 
   Fourier[Join[dat, ConstantArray[0, (n - 1) Length[dat]]]] Sqrt[n]
interpolatedFourier[dat, 2]
(* {1.53116 + 0. I, -0.022339 + 1.03333 I, -0.0783886 - 0.207404 I, 
    0.339664 + 0.429062 I, -0.298173 + 0.179654 I, 
    0.0707628 - 0.0261038 I, -0.0245808 + 0.0339534 I, 
    0.279942 + 0.0442931 I, -0.0390086 + 0.501077 I, -0.380536 + 
    0.0354403 I, -0.075875 - 1.97484*10^-17 I, -0.380536 - 
    0.0354403 I, -0.0390086 - 0.501077 I, 
    0.279942 - 0.0442931 I, -0.0245808 - 0.0339534 I, 
    0.0707628 + 0.0261038 I, -0.298173 - 0.179654 I, 
    0.339664 - 0.429062 I, -0.0783886 + 0.207404 I, -0.022339 - 
    1.03333 I} *)
```

Note that with `n==2`, every other point matches the uninterpolated version.

Added note: if you're really after speed, the FFT is most efficient when the length of the array is a power of two. So, it may be useful to pad out to such a length. The resulting transform will have increased resolution, but will not sample the same frequencies the unpadded FFT sampled unless its length was a power of 2. Details are left to the reader.

Comment: If you use powers of 2^2, wouldn't that make it "fourier"? (with apologies to Neal Sloane)